# Side effects of pushing fresh repo to existing Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Git repo that I have been pushing to Beanstalk via `git aws.push`.

This repo has 600MB of junk in it from past experiments where binaries needed to be pushed to Beanstalk along with the code.  I need to clean this up before opening the project to others to clone.  Rather than fighting with rebasing and hoping I clean everything out correctly, I intend to (after making a backup) delete the `.git` directories, `git init`, and start over using the code at this point in time as my initial commit.

After I do this, will there be any side effects I need to be concerned with when running `git aws.push`?  Will the fact that I have already pushed an effectively different Git repo to my Beanstalk environments somehow break my ability to push a completely new repo to those environments?

Comment: "aws.push" basically copies everything from the folder except ".git" folder into S3 bucket as an archive (zip) and keeps it ready for the EC2 instance (inside beanstalk app) to download. EC2 instance erases everything locally, and starts fresh (except the changes, if any, made using .ebextensions). So basically, you can push from any git repository. aws.push won't really care.

Comment: @RakeshBollampally Awesome, thank you.  Please post that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"aws.push" basically copies everything from the folder except ".git" folder into S3 bucket as an archive (zip) and keeps it ready for the EC2 instance (inside beanstalk app) to download. EC2 instance erases everything locally, and starts fresh (except the changes, if any, made using .ebextensions). So basically, you can push from any git repository. aws.push won't really care.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of eb cli are you using?
I would recommend keeping a backup copy of your entire git repo anyways before deleting the junk. Preferably experiment with the copy first.

Comment: I'm using v2.6.0, and yes I do plan to make a backup before this task.  I'm not concerned about the safety of the local repo... I'm worried about the remote on Amazon.